# Match word from given substring using REGEX

Tags: php, regex

i want to mach a word having a part of the word and a big text as a stack. I can do the match but i need it to have the smallest possible number of extra characters from the given substring.
The pattern i am using now is this `'/\b([a-zA-Z0-9]*?'.$substring.'[a-zA-Z0-9]*?)\b/'` where `$substring` is the substring variable, i need the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` parts to be as small as possible, i am trying to do that with lazy `*?`  match but i dont think its working.
Any ideas?

```
$substring='object';
preg_match('/\b([a-zA-Z0-9]*?'.$substring.'[a-zA-Z0-9]*?)\b/', 'As a stage on   which objects objectified are located and where the dramas of their ', $matches);
```

I need only `'objects'` and not `'objectified'`. Is there a better way than just going through the array and checking it in php?

Comment: have you tried `\S` or `\w`?

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs and expected matches.

Comment: I know you have asked for a regex solution, but have you looked at preg_match? I mention it just incase you haven't heard of it before.

Comment: Cannot do that as simple as that having just one regex.